# C# type of empty list

Tags: c#, .net, list, reflection, types

I can get a type of non empty list:

```
private Type GetListType(IEnumerable list)
{
  return list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
}
```

How i can get a type of empty list?

```
private Type GetListType(IEnumerable list)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Same, as long as the list is initialized.  If you are asking how to get a type when list == null, then you dont have a type.

Comment: Note that your code is buggy: try `GetListType (new ArrayList ()) ;`

Answer (score 5):

Your code works for empty lists too. The `[0]` is an indexer over the array of type arguments returned by the [`GetGenericArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) call, not your list's contents.

Comment: If only there were a way for him to test it before asking... :)

Answer (score 4):

The code you have works, e.g. in

```
GetListType(new List<string>()); // typeof(string)
```

It will not work if the runtime type doesn't have a generic parameter, e.g.

```
public class MyList : List<SomeObject> { }
GetListType(new MyList()); // there is no 0'th generic argument!
```

Or it might not return what you're expecting:

```
GetListType(new Dictionary<string, int>()); // typeof(string)
// even though it ought to be KeyValuePair<string, int>
```

Maybe you should use this instead:

```
private Type GetListType<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
{
  return typeof(T);
}
```

The biggest downside of this is that your type must implement `IEnumerable<T>`, not just `IEnumerable` (but if you wanted to get a useful type from an empty list, it'd have to do this, or otherwise declare its type, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out the code you have will work fine with an empty collection.  But it will only work when the collection type directly contains a generic variable.  It will not work for concrete collections.  For example

```
class IntList : List<int> { } 

GetListType(new List<int>()) // Works
GetListType(new IntList())   // Fails
```

The type `IntList` has no generic parameters hence the index operation `[0]` will fail.

To make a more general purpose implementation you should pick a particular interface or class type in which to query for the generic parameter.  I would recommend `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
static Type GetListType(IEnumerable enumerable)
{
    var type = enumerable.GetType();
    var enumerableType = type
        .GetInterfaces()
        .Where(x => x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
        .First();
    return enumerableType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
}
```